# Where is this scene from the Star Trek original series remastered edition?

Tags: star-trek

I'm reading this article: https://trekmovie.com/2016/09/06/retrospective-the-original-series-remastered-project/

The widescreen image of the small building on an island in a canyon with a ringed planet and blue sky....where is that from?

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's from the ninth episode of the first season of Star Trek: The Original Series, entitled *Dagger of the Mind*. You can see the shot in [this comparison](https://youtu.be/JENq2c-cRME?t=127) of the old and new VFX. The digital matte painting was created by visual effects artist [Maximilian Gabl](http://www.maxgabl.com/index.html) as part of his work on the remastered versions.

Comment: You might want to include some info about the matte picture artist; https://www.renderosity.com/star-trek-the-original-series-remastered-takes-max-gabl-where-no-matte-painter-has-gone-before-cms-14558

Comment: nice find! i must have missed this when watching all the episodes a while ago..

Answer (score 1):

This website has pictures from all Star Trek episodes  including remastered versions.
You can see this picture on the photo gallery for Star Trek the original series remastered s1 episode 9 dagger of the mind 
http://tos.trekcore.com/hd/thumbnails.php?album=10&page=8